navigation back causes a white screen overlay on previous destination in jetpack compose
A white screen or an unknown background sometimes appears when I press the back icon, which triggers { navController.navigateUp() }. This behavior does not occur consistently but happens randomly, and there are no logs related to it. I suspect the issue might be connected to the NavHost animations.
If the solution involves removing the NavHost background color (e.g., Color.White), my question is: why does this issue occur randomly? Additionally, if the screen is opaque white, the icons behind it (as shown in the image) should not be visible, yet they are.
NavHost(navController = navController,
    startDestination = NavigationMenuItem.Registration.name,  // Screen.PatientQueueScreen.route
    modifier = modifier
        .background(color = Color.White) {
{

    composable(route = NavigationMenuItem.Registration.name) {
        val viewModel: PatientSearchViewModel = viewModel()
        PatientSearchScreen(viewModel, navController, loadingViewModel)
    }
    composable(route = NavigationMenuItem.Admission.name) {

        val viewModel: PatientQueueViewModel = viewModel()
        AdmissionsScreen(viewModel, navController, loadingViewModel)
    }
}

Edited
For those who answered removing the background colour will solve it , i added 2 more screen shots after removing the background colour.
1st is still the faded version like overlay of navhost background colour this time a transparent or default navhost colour
2nd is the original perfect screen




NavHost crossfades between screens by default - you'd expect to see the background color in the middle on the animation (since both screens would be semi-transparent in the middle of the animation). Are you seeing something different than that?

It happens sometime only like 1 out of 8 time, either i saw the above same white shadowed image or my main content screen perfectly

Remove the fixed background color from NavHost to avoid issues with background layering during transitions.
Use smooth transition animations to ensure screens fade in and out without leaving artifacts.
Ensure proper state restoration when navigating back using navigateUp().
Check for navigation stack integrity to avoid UI inconsistencies.

Can you make it more precise as i already mentioned if removing the background colour is the solution then why it didn't happen every time i navigateUp. Majorly i want to know the cause of the problem not a general answer.
But thanks for the effort :)

Navhost background serves as a fallback visual element when the content isn't ready to be displayed. So if it's happening randomly it could be because for that instance the content is taking longer time to load due to some async operations like loading data from database or network call.
